# Pandas Bar Chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have just moved to pandas 0.20 / matplotlib 2.0 python 3.6. (form the version below in all).
I've used pandas to plot bar charts because matplotlib was always too low level.
The behaviour of colouring columns has now changed and I don't know how to fix that.
It used to be the following:

```
np.random.seed(42)
d = pd.Series(data=np.random.rand(10), index=range(10))
color=np.random.rand(10,4)

d.plot.bar(color=color)
```

producing:

[image: Old Version]

But now the chart produces:

[image: New Version]

So that the first color is picked up but not the rest.

Wondering if it's a bug or a new methodology, though I can't find a correct reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass color as a list:

```
np.random.seed(42)
d = pd.Series(data=np.random.rand(10), index=range(10))
color=np.random.rand(10,4)

d.plot.bar(color=[color])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for that quick answer. An odd change.

Comment: @TanguyBretagne Yeah, I am looking for documentation on it right now

Comment: @TanguyBretagne I think I found it, it was a change in Pandas. 
 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3486  From what's new in 0.19.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#id5